# Can`t connect to host via socks proxy in perl

Tags: perl, sockets, socks, lwp

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5) Gecko/20060719 Firefox/1.5.0.5');
$ua->proxy('http' => 'socks://188.26.223.189:1080');
my $response = $ua->get('http://example.com');
print $response->code,' ', $response->message,"\n";
print $response->decoded_content . "\n";
```

I try to connect to website via socks-proxy, but I get error: 500 Can't connect to example.com:80
What I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have the Perl module [LWP::Protocol::socks](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::socks) installed?

Comment: Yes, I installed it.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://mlawire.blogspot.com/2009/07/using-lwp-with-tor.html). Except for the `[ qw/http https/ ]`, it looks pretty much the same.

Comment: This doesn`t work too.

Comment: Dang. I was hoping for a miracle here. See if you can "telnet" to the proxy (`$ telnet 188.26.223.189 1080`). I wonder if you need user name and password on the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

This may mean one of three things:

1. your proxy at 188.26.223.189:1080 doesn't work
2. example.com doesn't work
3. example.com doesn't work for 188.26.223.189

`LWP::Protocol::socks` uses `IO::Socket::Socks` as SOCKS library. So, you may turn on the debugging by defining `SOCKS_DEBUG` environment variable:

```
SOCKS_DEBUG=1 perl test.pl
```

This will show you a SOCKS handshake. So you may see was this handshake success or not (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1928.txt).

You may also try to connect directly through `IO::Socket::Socks` to see will it success:

```
perl -MIO::Socket::Socks -E 'IO::Socket::Socks->new(ProxyAddr => "188.26.223.189", ProxyPort => 1080, ConnectAddr => "example.com", ConnectPort => 80, Timeout => 30, SocksDebug => 1) or die $SOCKS_ERROR; say "Connected!"'
```